# Django aws error while creating in elastic beanstalk

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm using elastic beanstalk and using below command trying to deploy django in aws-elasticbeanstalk but, it is showing above error.

```
eb init -p python-3.6 eb-django
```

I'm also pasting my project tree.

I'm getting following errors:

```
        Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 635, in _build_master
        ws.require(__requires__)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 943, in require
        needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 834, in resolve
        raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
    pkg_resources.ContextualVersionConflict: (urllib3 1.24.1 (/home/soubhagya/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages), Requirement.parse('urllib3<1.23,>=1.21.1'), {'awsebcli'})

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/bin/eb", line 5, in <module>
        from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2927, in <module>
        @_call_aside
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2913, in _call_aside
        f(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2940, in _initialize_master_working_set
        working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 637, in _build_master
        return cls._build_from_requirements(__requires__)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 650, in _build_from_requirements
        dists = ws.resolve(reqs, Environment())
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 834, in resolve
        raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
    pkg_resources.ContextualVersionConflict: (requests 2.9.1 (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages), Requirement.parse('requests!=2.18.0,>=2.14.2'), {'docker'})
```

[image]

Comment: did you try installing required packages manually for ex pip install requests and pip install urllib3

Comment: You might have an older version of the EBCLI. Can you run `pip install --upgrade awsebcli`? Depending on where you've installed it, you might need `sudo`.